# Discord.js deleting field and replacing it with a new one

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I'm trying to replace an embed with another embed with the same things, but I want to replace a field. Here's what I've got so far:

```js
const modlog = bot.channels.cache.get("770389813345255454");
const caseNumber = args[0];
const newReason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

await modlog.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then((messages) => {
    const caseLog = messages
        .filter((m) => m.author.id === bot.user.id && m.embeds[0] && m.embeds[0].type === "rich" && m.embeds[0].footer && m.embeds[0].footer.text.startsWith("Case") && m.embeds[0].footer.text === `Case ${caseNumber}`)
        .first();
    modlog.messages.fetch(caseLog.id).then((logMsg) => {
        const embed = logMsg.embeds[0];
        let newEmb = new MessageEmbed(embed).spliceFields(2, 1); // field 2 is the one i want to delete, and i want to delete 1 field.
        newEmb.addField("Reason:", newReason);
        logMsg.edit(newEmb);
    });
});
```

I try the command and it doesn't delete the other field but adds the new field. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you debug the code and answer what is stored in `newEmb`, does it an object or `undefined`, And just to notice, there are different ways to copy objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the field directly without using `spliceFields()`. `embed.fields` contains an array of fields so you can access an element by its index.

If you want to edit the second field, you can update `embed.fields[1]`. You can assign a new object with name, value, and inline keys. The new object would be `{ name: 'Reason', value: newReason }` in your case.

Check out the snippet below. I've also changed those `.then()`s to `await`s as you're already using them.

```js
const messages = await modlog.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 });
const caseLog = messages
  .filter(
    (m) =>
      m.author.id === bot.user.id &&
      m.embeds[0] &&
      m.embeds[0].type === 'rich' &&
      m.embeds[0].footer &&
      m.embeds[0].footer.text.startsWith('Case') &&
      m.embeds[0].footer.text === `Case ${caseNumber}`,
  )
  .first();

const logMsg = await modlog.messages.fetch(caseLog.id);
const embed = logMsg.embeds[0];

// the second field is index 1
embed.fields[1] = { name: 'Reason', value: newReason };

logMsg.edit(embed);
```

If you want to use `spliceFields()`, you can replace the field by adding a third argument, the same object I mentioned above:

```js
const logMsg = await modlog.messages.fetch(caseLog.id);
const embed = logMsg.embeds[0];

// the second field is index 1
embed.spliceFields(1, 1, { name: 'Reason', value: newReason });

logMsg.edit(embed);
```